# How can I balance 1 collection into multiple other collections based on a variable?

Tags: algorithm

Essentially, I have a total of 20 players, and they each have 2 properties;

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "goals": 20
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to feed the list of players and their goals into an algorithm that divides the teams up evenly into 2 teams, but does it based on their goals and balances the teams with as small a difference as possible. The number of players will always be divisible by 2, so that is no issue!

For example, say we have 4 (for brevity sake) players in a single array/collection;

1. "John Doe" - 5 goals
2. "Jane Doe" - 1 goal
3. "James Doe" - 3 goals
4. "Mark Doe" - 7 goals

After going through the algorithm, this would result in 2 separate arrays/collections like so;

```
|    Team 1     |    Team 2     |
|---------------|---------------|
| John Doe      | Jane Doe      |
| James Doe     | Mark Doe      |
|               |               |
| Avg: 4 Goals  | Avg: 4 Goals  |
|               |               |
| Goal Total: 8 | Goal Total: 8 |
```

Obviously there will be times where both teams are not exactly equal, but ideally I'd want it to get as close as possible in those situations. E.G say Team 1 has 8 goals and Team 2 has 7 goals.

Comment: How about first sorting the players based on their goals, and then take one player from the front, another from the end, pair them up, and put them in a team? For example, suppose after sorting the goals are, ``15, 11, 9 , 6``, then `15` & `6` will be in one team, and `11` & `9` will be in another. You just have to toggle between team 1 and 2 when pairing.

Comment: @Robur_131 Is it possible you could elaborate a bit on what "toggle between team 1 and 2 when pairing" means? Is it also possible you could provide a bit of pseudo-code to help me understand you explanation a little better? :)

Comment: Nice question. Now my suggestion would be following 1. Dynamic programming : Knapsack algorithm 2. use this simple method :  Divide array in two equal subelement with almost same sum https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dividing-array-two-halves-sum/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem ?

Comment: @Robur_131: That toggling assumes a certain evenness in distribution.  Consider a pool with a distribution that's more typically skewed, such as `[20, 12, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3]`.  Pairing fails altogether here, even with a 1-2-2... alternation: `[20, 8, 5, 4]` is still an incorrect solution.  You need an algorithm that can recognize `[20, 6, 5, 3]` as acceptable.

Comment: This is a particular case of the "target sum" algorithm (half the elements close to a computed value) or the "Partitioning problem".  With those keywords, your browser search should find you a solution.

Comment: Yes, greedy solution will fail in this case. It needs a dynamic programming solution.

Comment: @Prune It's easier to find out the optimal minimized difference between the two teams by straightforward DP. But we need to keep track of which members actually lead to optimal solution. Will it increase complexity ?

Comment: No, recording the solution you've just traversed does not increase complexity.

Comment: @Prune I posted an answer. Can you have a look and give feedback?

Comment: @Robur_131 Apologies, but my review may be a while -- you provided two test cases (yay!), and I have a busy schedule as of late yesterday.  Also, I'm the person who voted to close this: despite references to a couple of classes of solutions, OP has shown no effort to solve the problem.  I would expect OP to review and test the solution first.

Comment: Nevertheless, I would love your feedback. Please do give one whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

I had previously mentioned in the comment that a greedy solution (after sorting the input) will work. But as pointed out by `@Prune` and others, a greedy solution will not work here, rather a dynamic programming solution is needed. Following is my implementation is `C++`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

class Pair{
    public:
        int difference;
        std::vector <int> solution;

        Pair(){
            difference = -1;
            solution.clear();
        }

        Pair(int d, std::vector <int> v) : difference(d), solution(v){}

        bool operator < (const Pair &p) const{
            return difference < p.difference;
        }
};

class Player{
    public:
        std::string name;
        int goals;

        Player() = default;
        Player(std::string n, int g) : name(n), goals(g) {}

        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Player &player);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Player &player){
    out << "Player Name: " << player.name << " Player Goals: " << player.goals;
    return out;
}

constexpr int MAX_PLAYER = 6;
constexpr int MAX_GOAL = 101;
constexpr int INF = 1e9;

Pair dp[MAX_PLAYER + 5][MAX_GOAL + 5];

Pair partition(std::vector <Player> players, int index, int val, std::vector <int> result, int sum){
    if(index == players.size() || result.size() == (players.size() / 2)){
        int oppostion = sum - val;
        if(result.size() == players.size() / 2) return Pair(std::abs(val - oppostion), result); 
        return Pair(INF, std::vector <int>()); // return a high difference + empty vector
    }

    if(dp[index][val].difference != -1) {
        return dp[index][val];
    }

    Pair ret1 = partition(players, index + 1, val,  result, sum);
    result.push_back(index);
    Pair ret2 = partition(players, index + 1, val + players[index].goals, result, sum);
    //std::cout << " index " << index << " val " << val << "\n";

    return dp[index][val] = (ret1 < ret2 ? ret1 : ret2);
}

std::vector <Player> readInput(std::ifstream &ifs){
    std::vector <Player> players;
    std::string inputLine;
    while(std::getline(ifs, inputLine)){
        std::istringstream iss(inputLine);
        std::string name;
        int goals;
        iss >> name >> goals;
        players.emplace_back(name, goals);
    }
    return players;
}

auto accumulate_func = [](int accumulator, const Player& player){
   return accumulator + player.goals;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);
    std::ifstream ifs("in.txt");
    std::vector <Player> players = readInput(ifs);

    int sumGoals = std::accumulate(players.begin(), players.end(), 0, accumulate_func);

    std::cout << "Total Goals: " << sumGoals << "\n";

    Pair ret = partition(players, 0, 0, std::vector <int> (), sumGoals);
    std::cout << "Optimal goal difference " << ret.difference << '\n';

    std::vector <Player> teamA;
    std::vector <Player> teamB;

    std::vector <int> teamAIndices;

    for(int index : ret.solution){
        teamAIndices.push_back(index);
        teamA.push_back(players[index]);
    }

    for(int i = 0, k = 0 ; i < players.size() ; ++i){
        if(i == teamAIndices[k]){
            // this player has already been considered
            k++;
        } else{
            teamB.push_back(players[i]);
        }
    }


    std::cout << "-----Team A-----\n";
    for(const Player &player : teamA){
        std::cout << player << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "-----Team B-----\n";
    for(const Player &player : teamB){
        std::cout << player << "\n";
    }

    int goalsTeamA = std::accumulate(teamA.begin(), teamA.end(), 0, accumulate_func);
    int goalsTeamB = std::accumulate(teamB.begin(), teamB.end(), 0, accumulate_func);

    std::cout << "\nGoals of Team A: " << goalsTeamA << " Goals of Team B: " << goalsTeamB << "\n";
    std::cout << "Average goals of Team A: " << goalsTeamA / static_cast <double> (teamA.size()) << " Average goals of Team B: " << goalsTeamB / static_cast <double> (teamB.size()) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
John_Doe 10
Jane_Doe 15
James_Doe 7
Mark_Doe 25
X_Doe 9
Y_Doe 31
Z_Doe 3
A_Doe 1
```

Output:

```
Total Goals: 101
Optimal goal difference 1
-----Team A-----
Player Name: John_Doe Player Goals: 10
Player Name: X_Doe Player Goals: 9
Player Name: Y_Doe Player Goals: 31
Player Name: A_Doe Player Goals: 1

-----Team B-----
Player Name: Jane_Doe Player Goals: 15
Player Name: James_Doe Player Goals: 7
Player Name: Mark_Doe Player Goals: 25
Player Name: Z_Doe Player Goals: 3

Goals of Team A: 51 Goals of Team B: 50
Average goals of Team A: 12.75 Average goals of Team B: 12.5
```

I've put an underscore between the first name and last name of the players because I didn't want to deal with input parsing very much (variable number of name parts separated by whitespace...). You can just replace the `_` by a space.

For the input mentioned in the post, it gives:

```
Total Goals: 16
Optimal goal difference 0
-----Team A-----
Player Name: John_Doe Player Goals: 5
Player Name: James_Doe Player Goals: 3

-----Team B-----
Player Name: Jane_Doe Player Goals: 1
Player Name: Mark_Doe Player Goals: 7

Goals of Team A: 8 Goals of Team B: 8
Average goals of Team A: 4 Average goals of Team B: 4
```

The input given by `@Prune` in the comments:

```
John_Doe 20
Jane_Doe 12
James_Doe 10
Mark_Doe 8
X_Doe 6
Y_Doe 5
Z_Doe 4
A_Doe 3
```

Output:

```
Total Goals: 68
Optimal goal difference 0
-----Team A-----
Player Name: Jane_Doe Player Goals: 12
Player Name: James_Doe Player Goals: 10
Player Name: Mark_Doe Player Goals: 8
Player Name: Z_Doe Player Goals: 4

-----Team B-----
Player Name: John_Doe Player Goals: 20
Player Name: X_Doe Player Goals: 6
Player Name: Y_Doe Player Goals: 5
Player Name: A_Doe Player Goals: 3

Goals of Team A: 34 Goals of Team B: 34
Average goals of Team A: 8.5 Average goals of Team B: 8.5
```

**Change the `MAX_PLAYER` and `MAX_GOALS` according to input.**